# How to get a subset DataTable from another DataTable filtered by few column values?

Tags: c#, datatable, subset, rowfilter

The problem I have is, my search criteria is:

```
Row["colName"] != "abc"  AND 
Row["colName"] != "def"  AND 
Row["colName"] != "ghic"  AND 
Row["colName"] != "klm"  AND
Row["colName"] != "xyz"  AND 
Row["colName"] != "mnp"  etc..
```

in other words, after my research I found something about `DefaultView` of the `DataTable` and `RowFilter`, but `Rowfilter` seems to  filter only by one value.

My situation is I need to filter by a bunch of values.

Thanks

Comment: Have no idea why I got a -1 for this question. I could not find a clearer question and a clearer answer below. Actually I could not find a similar question either.  In addition the answer below is very elegant

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `Linq-To-DataTable` and a collection of values to exclude.

Query Syntax:

```
string[] exclude = { "def", "ghic", "klm", "xyz", "mnp" };
var filteredRows = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                   where !exclude.Contains(row.Field<string>("colName"))
                   select row;
DataTable result = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Method Syntax:

```
result = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => !exclude.Contains(r.Field<string>("colName")))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: I should try this with exclude really better solution than mine thanks +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` of the rows, and do a `Where` on that.

```
var criteria = new List<string>();
criteria.Add("abc");
criteria.Add("def");
criteria.Add("ghic");
//etc

var filteredRows = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => !criteria.Contains(row["colName"].ToString()));
```