# Event Data_Column_Changed is lost when a subset DataTable is derived from another DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datatable

[I used this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259631/how-to-get-a-subset-datatable-from-another-datatable-filtered-by-few-column-valu) to get a subset (DataTable2 for example) from an original Data Table(DataTable1-  for example).

It worked and I got the desired DataTable2, until I realized that the events that were assigned to the original DataTable1 do not exist for the subset (DataTable2).

How can I preserve the events associated with the first DataTable1?  The events in question are 
(Data_Column_Changed and DataRowChanged)

Comment: But it's a brand new `DataTable` object.  A sub-set of the data, but not of the original _table_.  You will have to assign the methods to it.

Comment: @DonBoitnott,ok, I did. It s working., Thanks.  I am wondering if there was a different way of getting the subset without losing the associated events.